# Can't click on a button with Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, click

I am trying to write a code which will type something in a search bar and click on the *search* button :

- the part about typing in the search bar is OK.
- but the part about clicking on the *search* button is a nightmare. I looked everywhere on Stackoverflow and I tried for hours but nothing I do seems to work...

**Website :** https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/topic-search

**The HTML structure I need to use to click the *search* button :**

`<button type="submit" id="f2q3fi9kd" class="btn ux-button btn-accent btn-lg ux-button--large ux-button--icon-only" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" data-e2e="ux-button">`

**Here is my code :**

**xxx = what I need to write to find the button**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

cc_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())) 
cc_driver.get('https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/topic-search')
action = ActionChains(cc_driver)

searchTextbox = WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Type your Keywords...']" )))
action.move_to_element(searchTextbox).click().send_keys("CREA-CROSS-2023-JOURPART-PLURALISM").perform()

save_Button = WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'xxx')))
action.move_to_element(save_Button).click()
```

**Update 1**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

cc_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())) 
cc_driver.get('https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/topic-search')
action = ActionChains(cc_driver)

# Perform Search
searchTextbox = WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Type your Keywords...']" )))
action.move_to_element(searchTextbox).click().send_keys("CREA-CROSS-2023-JOURPART-PLURALISM").perform()

# Try 1
save_Button = WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'icon-search.ux-u-font-size-h2')))
cc_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", save_Button)

# Try 2
save_Button = WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'icon-search.ux-u-font-size-h2')))
action.move_to_element(save_Button).click()
cc_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", save_Button)

# Try 3
save_Button = WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'icon-search.ux-u-font-size-h2')))
save_Button.click()

# Try 4
save_Button = WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'icon-search.ux-u-font-size-h2')))
save_Button.click()
cc_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", save_Button)
```

Comment: Is this what you intended to use : `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'xxx')`?

Comment: Ah no sorry!
xxx = where I tried many things to find the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cc_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
cc_driver.maximize_window()
cc_driver.get('https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/opportunities/topic-search')

searchTextbox = WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Type your Keywords...']" )))
searchTextbox.send_keys("CREA-CROSS-2023-JOURPART-PLURALISM")

save_Button = WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'icon-search.ux-u-font-size-h2')))
save_Button.click()
```

Comment: I tried it's not working...

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: When I run the code, a window opens, it types "CREA-CROSS-2023-JOURPART-PLURALISM" in the search bar, and then it immediately closes. The search is not carried out.
So there is no error, but it's not working either

Comment: Ok try the updated code now. Use java script to perform `click()`

Comment: Ok, sorry but I've never used JavaScript. Can you tell me in details what I am supposed to do ?
Thanks for helping me Shawn, it's very nice of you.

Comment: Because when I replace my 2 lines with your 2 lines it's still not working...

Comment: Share your latest updated code in the question. Let me have a look.

Comment: You can look at it at "Update 1".

Try 1, 2, 3 and 4 are the things I tested after your suggestions (none are working...)

Comment: Try the code in the updated answer. Just try As-Is.

Comment: I'm sorry it's not working... Is it working when you run the code Shawn ?

Comment: Yes it's working in my system. Not sure what is causing it not to work in you system. After the code is run does it immediately close the window? If yes, how are you sure its not clicking the search button? Add `time.sleep(20)` after the last line of the code and check if it actually clicks or not.

Comment: Oh you're right !! Thank you so so much.
Have a very good day Shawn